# Junit : how to make conditional tests?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I'm trying to write conditional tests with JUnit. I need to test the persistence of objects and if those tests pass, test access via HTTP methods (in order to develop a REST Web Service).

For this moment my solution looks like this :

```
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void testSuite() {
        final Request requestStatutTest = Request.method(this.getClass(), "insertStatutTest");
        final Result resStatutTest = new JUnitCore().run(requestStatutTest);
        if (resStatutTest.wasSuccessful()) {
            postStatutTest();
            getStatutTest();
            putStatutTest();
            deleteStatutTest();

    }

    public void insertStatutTest() {
    }

    public void postStatutTest() {
    }

    // etc...

}
```

Is it the good solution ?

Answer (score 10):

Rather than *assert* that the property is true, you can use `org.junit.Assume`:

```
 @Before
 public void checkAssumptions() {
     org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(someCondition());
     // or import static org.junit.Assume.* and then just call assumeTrue()
 }
```

If the condition is false, then this will result in the test ending with a violated assumption.  As [the docs say](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html):

> A failed assumption does not mean the code is broken, but that the test provides no useful information.

This is a weaker condition than a failed assertion (i.e. a test failure), and the default JUnit runner will treat this test as ignored.  Which sounds like exactly what you are looking for - run the test if the persistence works, otherwise ignore it.

Comment: Used assume with theories but never thought of using them this way. +1